# Why directly updating charater at index does not work in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can somebody explain this behaviour

**Code:**

```
name = "ABC"
console.log(name)

name[0] = "B"
console.log(name)
```

**Output Expected:**

```
ABC
BBC
```

**Actual Output :**
[image: Actual Output]

Comment: Not only that it doesn't work, if you are in a function with strict mode (`"use strict;"` as the first statement), it will throw an error, for example (in Chrome) `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string 'ABC'`

Comment: He asked for the reason why I think. Strings are immutable that is the reason why his code doesn't work

Comment: A [quote from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String): When using bracket notation for character access, attempting to delete or assign a value to these properties will not succeed. The properties involved are neither writable nor configurable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable/readonly due to the fact that they are primitive data types in JavaScript. You can only generate new strings.

```
name = "ABC"
console.log(name)

name = "B" + name.slice(1);
console.log(name)
```

To read more about primitives-[MDN-Primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)

Answer (score 0):

By creating a new string with the desired modification, you achieve the desired result while keeping the original name variable intact.

```
let name = "ABC";
console.log(name);

name = "B" + name.substring(1); // Concatenate "B" with the rest of the string
console.log(name);
```